# What is the best way to build a MySQL table to save logs?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering what could be the best way to build a MySQL Table to store "users logs" ; I'm dev'ing a website where users can do a lot of actions like adding content and informations about this content ; those informations are themselves store in differents tables, etc.

Anyway, so far I was thinking about two solutions :

```
ID | user_id | element_id | action(keyword) | action_informations (array with details) | date
```

Or :

```
ID | user_id | element_id | actions (array of multiple actions done between date 1 and date 2, meaning between login and the moment where no action are done anymore) | date1 | date2
```

The first solution really seems the cleanest but I'm scared the table scaling would be astronomic with more and more users and contents.

Maybe there's a better way than those, I'm all hears.

Comment: I wouldn't have multiple tables storing the same data. What amount of records are you going to be having, and how long do you need these logs to live for? With < 50 million records and proper indexing should be fine with one table.

Comment: One action - one row.

Comment: To reduce the logs size : Do you need to store all actions? Do you need to store it forever? To help us understand your needs : Why do you want to save this logs?

Comment: @user3783243 one data is in one table only, it's not stored in multiple tables, don't worry (i maybe misstell something). Truth be told, I can't know the amount of data, but I have to log every page the user sees, every action the user does, etc. So.. Huge.

Comment: @SeeoX I have to log almost everything because it's about "health datas", so I have to be able to say who did what and when if any problem should occur. About how long I should save it, we can count in decades !

Comment: First one seems fine. I would just suggest you to use an ENUM for the action column (if possible).

Comment: Thx for the advice @SeeoX ! I'll take a look :)